# Database search on html element returns nothing

Tags: mysql, wordpress, replace

So there's an element in html that I need to replace, but first I want to search for it.

The element is 
`<hr class="system-pagebreak">`

I know it is in posts because I've seen it, but doing a search in phpMyAdmin on the posts table yields zero results.

Comment: That HTML may be generated by a template tag like `<!--nextpage-->`. Open up one of the posts you've seen it in and examine it in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Thanks, it was my fault. My version of MySQL needed tilde signs. Also found that Better Search Replace plugin works just as well. Thanks.